# if else statement not executing right

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

I have a very funny behaviour of my if else statement. At start the memo is empty and attempted deletion triggers the message. Then if I write something in memo and try to delete, again the right message comes up. But then, after last deletion (memo is now empty) if I click once again to delete I get the second message and not the first (nothing to delete. Am I messing if else statements ?? What is the right way here ?

```
procedure TForm1.AdvGlowButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if advmemo1.IsEmpty then
      ShowMessage('Nothing to delete !')
   else  
   begin
     if MessageDlg('Delete everything?',
                     mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrYes then begin
       advmemo1.Lines.Clear;
       advmemo1.Lines.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+ '\memo.txt');
     end;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: For all practical purposes, you can count 100% on the fact that if/then/else statements will all be compiled and executed correctly. If it doesn't do what you expect, then the problem is in your own code, or in a library that you've using.

Comment: I don't get this example at all: first you clear the memo, then you savetofile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after saving you must call

```
advmemo1.RefreshMemo;
```

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with the code you showed, so obviously `IsEmpty` must be returning False after the last delete instead of returning True, which suggests that either 1) not everything was actually deleted like you thought, or 2) `IsEmpty` is buggy.

Comment: Find out why `IsEmpty` is not returning True when you are expecting it to.  Or else don't use `IsEmpty` anymore, find somethign else.

Comment: What kind of "strange results"?

Comment: if i just do the first part if advmemo1.IsEmpty then
      ShowMessage('Nothing to delete !') it works ok. I can write delete and memo detects if it is empty. This memo it seems needs carriage return to first line to detect empty memo.Weird

Comment: I think I found out what the problem was ... after saving you must call advmemo1.RefreshMemo; Then it works...Thank you !